# $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)$ (Without L'Hospital)

Tags: limits

I'm trying to find
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)$$
I think the answer is $\pi$, but I don't know how to find it.
Could you please show me the shortcut?

Answer (score 9):

**Hint**: The limit you are considering is exactly the same as

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x \cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)}\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)}$$

or alternatively, by replacing $x$ with $1/x$:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\cos{\left(\pi x\right)} \sin{\left(\pi x\right)}}{x}$$

and finally, replacing $x$ by $x/\pi$,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\cos{x} \sin{x}}{x/\pi}$$

Answer (score 6):

Consider a regular $2^{n}-\,$gon inscribed in a circle of radius $1$. Then the area of each of the $2^{n}$ isosceles triangles is $$A_n=\cos\frac{\pi}{2^n}\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}$$

Thus the total area is $$T_n=2^n\cos\frac{\pi}{2^n}\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}$$

*As $n$ grows large, this will approximate the area of the circle better and better*, and since this area is $\pi$, we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\cos\frac{\pi}{2^n}\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}=\pi$$

Of course, this is *less rigorous* than other approaches, but I think it is charming.

Comment: In essence, you could use this as a roundabout proof that $\sin x /x \to 1$..

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $\pi$. Use the fundamental limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

The proof depends on the  tools you can use. Perhaps it is obvious that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)=1,$$ 
since $\frac{\pi}{2^n}\to 0$, and the cosine function is continuous, and $cos(0)=1$.

Perhaps you also know that $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin h}{h}=1$. If you do, then rewrite $2^n \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)$ as:
$$\pi \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}.$$

Comment: @T.Bongers: Yes, that's what I mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 2^n\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)=2^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right) \sim 2^{n-1}\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}=\pi, $$

since $\sin(x)\sim x$ as $x\sim 0$.

Comment: Have you read Theo's answer, Mhenni?